# Why is Filter failing to take factors of a number?

Tags: r, operators, factors

I'm getting some strange behavior from some R code that I wrote to factor non-zero integers.

```
factors<-function(num) c(Filter(function(x) num%%x==0,(-num%/%2):num%/%2),num,-num)
```

I expected `factors(-15)` to give the sequence `-15, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 15`. Instead, I get:

```
> factors(-15)
 [1]   3   3   1   1  -1  -1  -3  -3  -5  -5 -15  15
```

On top of being ordered very strangely (shouldn't it have checked from -7 to 7?) this misses out 5. What have I overlooked?

Comment: Is there no tag for functions like Filter or Reduce? I couldn't find one.

Comment: There's the [tag:functional-programing] tag, but I don't think it's necessary in the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a couple of brackets

```
factors <- function(num) c(-num, Filter(function(x) num%%x==0, (-num%/%2):(num%/%2)), num)
factors(-15)
# [1]  15   5   3   1  -1  -3  -5 -15
```

By the way, it checks from -8 to 7 in this case

```
(-15%/%2):(15%/%2)
# [1] -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Why does ```num%/%2``` need to be bracketed? Is there an order of operation issue? What sequence was R using?

Comment: Yes, in your case R consider the `:` first, then the operator `%/%` if they are not bracketed. Have a look at this https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html

Comment: See `help("Syntax")` for the order of precedence.